# Создание и сравнение деревьев

Tags: c#, сравнение

Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с деревьями.
задача такова. Создать два дерева, такого типа: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

где n-положительное число.
Также необходимо рекурсивно и нерекурсивно описать функцию сравнения этих деревьев.

```
class Node
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public Node Left { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.Data = data;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int n = 50;
        Node A1 = new Node(n);
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            A1.Left = new Node(n - i) ;
            A1.Left.Left = new Node(n - 1);
        }
        Console.WriteLine(A1.Data);
        Console.WriteLine(A1.Left.Left.Data);
        Console.WriteLine(A1.Left.Data);
        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}
```

Основная сложность состоит в том, как циклично создать потомков дерева, т.е. после A1.Left, чтобы цикл создавал A1.Left.Left и так далее.
До сравнения пока не дошел. Но буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Создавайте потомков рекурсивно.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего инициализировать такие деревья рекурсивно:

```
class Node
{
    public int Data { get; set; }
    public Node Left { get; set; }
    public Node Right { get; set; }

    public Node(int data)
    {
        this.Data = data;

        if (data > 1)
        {
            this.Left = new Node(data - 1);
            this.Right = new Node(data - 1);
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const int n = 4;
        Node A1 = new Node(n);

        Console.WriteLine(A1.Data);
        Console.WriteLine(A1.Left.Left.Data);
        Console.WriteLine(A1.Left.Data);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

для второго дерева - поменяйте проверку и знак в конструкторе.

только осторожно, в дереве с N уровнями будет 2<sup>N</sup> нод. А 2<sup>50</sup> - это очень-очень большое число.